# PWA is still using old index.html file in Safari IOS

Tags: reactjs, safari, progressive-web-apps

The problem was due to white screen of death after deploying PWA (This is really hard to reproduce but it is an ongoing issue for my clients). It seems to be the problem with cache. It is causing `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'`. I know many thread talked about this but it doesn't seem to directly let me tackle and reproduce the issue.

The closest to be able to reproduce is by doing this.

1. Add PWA to home screen
2. Open PWA
3. Edit index.html to have `.js` file pointing to wrong hash in /var/www/my-server
4. When I reopen the PWA it is still serving the old index.html file.
5. Clearing Safari cache in my iPhone does nothing. PWA still serving old index.html file.

How can I debug what causing the phone to be using the old `index.html` file even when server already change the index.html file content?

1. I am using cloudflare
2. I am not configuring any Service Worker